# Can a crawler detect an email on my javascript?

Tags: spam-prevention, email-spam

i don't like spam, and i don't know how crawlers work, so my question is:

if the make a js "mouseenter" on my website to change a word to my email, am i vulnerable to bot spam?

Cheers and thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you asking if it's impossible for a crawler to run javascript and then search for an email? No, it's not impossible

Comment: yes, something like that, any way i could share my email while keeping it safe from bots?